# Reduce array of object properties to nested object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I have an array with increasing specificity eg.

```js
const locationProperties = ['earth', 'americas', 'canada', 'saskatchewan'];
```

and I would like an object:

```js
{
 earth: {
  americas: {
   canada: {
    saskatchewan: {
      // data 
    }
   }  
  }
 }
}
```

I was thinking to use `.reduce` to create the object but after applying the transformation in the reducer I am only left with `{}`

```js
const reducer = (accumulator, item) => {
  accumulator[item] = {};
  return accumulator[item];
}

const reducedArray = locationProperties.reduce(reducer, {});
```

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend a simple recursion function, `nest` -

```js
const nest = ([key, ...more], val) =>
  key == null
    ? val
    : {[key]: nest(more, val)}
    
const loc =
  ['earth', 'americas', 'canada', 'saskatchewan']    

console.log(nest(loc, "something"))
```

```js
{
  "earth": {
    "americas": {
      "canada": {
        "saskatchewan": "something"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can also use `reduceRight` -

```js
const loc =
  ['earth', 'americas', 'canada', 'saskatchewan']    

const result =
  loc.reduceRight((val, key) => ({[key]: val}), "something")

console.log(result)
```

```json
{
  "earth": {
    "americas": {
      "canada": {
        "saskatchewan": "something"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Since you are familiar with `reduce` I will point out that `arr.reduceRight(...)` is the effectively the equivalent of `arr.reverse().reduce(...)`. However using `reduceRight` is more efficient in this case and will not mutate the input array -

```js
const loc =
  ['earth', 'americas', 'canada', 'saskatchewan']    

const result =
  loc.reverse().reduce((val, key) => ({[key]: val}), "something")

console.log(result)
```

```json
{
  "earth": {
    "americas": {
      "canada": {
        "saskatchewan": "something"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow. This is beautiful. I like this solution a lot. I also tried to solve this question, but mine isn't as beautiful as yours. I think it will be more perfect if you change the argument `"something"` to `{}`?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Miu. I really appreciate it. I made the inner var `"something"` to signal that it can be whatever the caller wants. Also I didn't want people to get confused thinking `{}` was the beginning of the outermost object.

Comment: I got it :) Thank you for your kind reply. Now I fully agree with you and "something" :)